# Find caller of function in C++ (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio 2015 C++ project which doesn't run under WinXP, because a function getTickCount64() is called somewhere (only Vista and higher). The function is in an external library Kernel32.dll, so I cannot declare it as deprecated to get compiler warnings.

I checked many times, and I'm not calling the function myself, it has to be in a 3rd party lib I'm using.

How can I figure out where the function gets called?

Comment: I think you need to debug it ... https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I'd use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the executable to find out. @UKMonkey a program with a missing dependency will not launch at all, much less be debuggable.

Comment: @Quentin correct, but it doesn't have a missing dependency, the dll exists.  The function in the dll does not, so it will fail at runtime.

Comment: You should debug it and view the call stack when that function is called.

Comment: @UKMonkey kind of, it will fail instantly at load time with a message of this kind: http://www.syncios.com/images/online_help/entry-point-not-found.png

Comment: @Quentin that part is application specific.  Which is why debugging is required.  (The alternative, is that it could try to load the function, fail, and then chose to use another function!)

Comment: @UKMonkey: no, it is not application-specific. The OS loader itself throws that error when it tries to load any executable that has a static dependency on a missing DLL function. You won't have any chance to debug the executable, as the process is not created at all.

Comment: @UKMonkey but no debugging is possible, since the program plain won't start.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function breakpoint (Debug->New Breakpoint->Function breakpoint) and then the call stack to see where it is getting called from.

Comment: That only works if the app is successfully loaded at runtime.  If the function is linked to statically, the app will fail to load.

Comment: Loading the app succesfully is no problem. I'll just do it under Win7!
Ok that solution sound good to me, problem is, its not a simple executable I'm talking about, but a VST-plugin (= sound thingy) which has to be loaded into a digital audio workstation. So I'll have to figure out how to debug that stuff...

Thanks for the answer anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to find the culprit at runtime with a debugger, as your program will fail to load at runtime.  You will have to search every 3rd party library your app uses statically until you find the one that calls that function statically.  If you don't have the source code for the libraries, you could at least search the object files or import libs that you link you app with, looking for any reference to the function.